# Updating VM state in ovrt python sdk script

Tags: python, sdk

I'm trying to write a python script to query the status of VM's in ovirt (I'm completely new to python!)

Here's a test script I'm using!

```
APIURL="https://..."
APIUSER="...@..."
APIPASS="..."
CAFILE="path"
LOGFILENAME="/tmp/shutdown_vms_dc.log"


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                filename=LOGFILENAME,
                filemode='w')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        api = API(url=APIURL,
          username=APIUSER,
          password=APIPASS,
          ca_file=CAFILE)
        print 'Connected to RHEVM API  %s Successfully' % APIURL
    logging.info ( 'Successfully Connected to %s' % APIURL)

    vmsList = api.vms.list()
    while True:
        print '###############################################'
            for i in vmsList:
                    if i.name != 'HostedEngine':
                            print i.name + ': '  + i.status.state
        time.sleep(10)
```

except Exception as ex:
        logging.debug('Unexpected error: %s' % ex)

The problem is that the state does not get updated, it always prints as the first time it runs. I shut down and start VM's with ovirt's web interface and nothing changes... What I'm missing???

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I was mistaken... 
The line
`vmList=api.vms.list()`
leaves you with static data related to when you made the call.

So, I achieved what I wanted inside the for loop by calling:
`api.vms.get(i.name).status.state`, where `i` iterates the `vmList` obtained in first place! That did the trick!